# What is the best way to know missing numbers in a sortedset in Redis?

Tags: redis

If I have a SortedSet in Redis that just contains integer values, let's say from 1-2million, is there a performant way to quickly figure out the missing integer values in the SortedSet? Or, would a different data structure besides a SortedSet be better for this type of lookup ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try bit operations: [setbit](http://redis.io/commands/setbit). Instead of storing the integer into Redis, you can take the integer as a bit position/offset. In a word, use a `bitmap` to store the existence of an integer.

When you try to store an integer, set the corresponding bit with `setbit` command. When you want to check missing integers, get the value, and check positions where the bit values are `0`.

> Store integers

```
// store 2
setbit key 2 1
// store 123
setbit key 123 1
// store N
setbit key N 1
```

> Find missing integers

```
// get value
get key
// Check each bit of the returned value.
// If the bit value is 0, the position/offset of this bit is a missing integer
```